# ILendingPool.getReserveData function gives YulException: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly:

Tags: solidity

I am trying to call the `getReserveData` function of a library `ILendingPool` interface:

```
interface ILendingPool {
  function addressesProvider () external view returns ( address );
  function deposit ( address _reserve, uint256 _amount, uint16 _referralCode ) external payable;
  function redeemUnderlying ( address _reserve, address _user, uint256 _amount ) external;
  function borrow ( address _reserve, uint256 _amount, uint256 _interestRateMode, uint16 _referralCode ) external;
  function repay ( address _reserve, uint256 _amount, address _onBehalfOf ) external payable;
  function swapBorrowRateMode ( address _reserve ) external;
  function rebalanceFixedBorrowRate ( address _reserve, address _user ) external;
  function setUserUseReserveAsCollateral ( address _reserve, bool _useAsCollateral ) external;
  function liquidationCall ( address _collateral, address _reserve, address _user, uint256 _purchaseAmount, bool _receiveAToken ) external payable;
  function flashLoan ( address _receiver, address _reserve, uint256 _amount, bytes calldata _params ) external;
  function getReserveConfigurationData ( address _reserve ) external view returns ( uint256 ltv, uint256 liquidationThreshold, uint256 liquidationDiscount, address interestRateStrategyAddress, bool usageAsCollateralEnabled, bool borrowingEnabled, bool fixedBorrowRateEnabled, bool isActive );
  function getReserveData ( address _reserve ) external view returns ( uint256 totalLiquidity, uint256 availableLiquidity, uint256 totalBorrowsFixed, uint256 totalBorrowsVariable, uint256 liquidityRate, uint256 variableBorrowRate, uint256 fixedBorrowRate, uint256 averageFixedBorrowRate, uint256 utilizationRate, uint256 liquidityIndex, uint256 variableBorrowIndex, address aTokenAddress, uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp );
  function getUserAccountData ( address _user ) external view returns ( uint256 totalLiquidityETH, uint256 totalCollateralETH, uint256 totalBorrowsETH, uint256 availableBorrowsETH, uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold, uint256 ltv, uint256 healthFactor );
  function getUserReserveData ( address _reserve, address _user ) external view returns ( uint256 currentATokenBalance, uint256 currentUnderlyingBalance, uint256 currentBorrowBalance, uint256 principalBorrowBalance, uint256 borrowRateMode, uint256 borrowRate, uint256 liquidityRate, uint256 originationFee, uint256 variableBorrowIndex, uint256 lastUpdateTimestamp, bool usageAsCollateralEnabled );
  function getReserves () external view;
}
```

Unfortunately the `getReserveData` function returns a ***`tuple`*** that has **13** fields.

I need only one of the fields and you can see me call it below:

```
   function getAvailableLiquidity(ILendingPool _lendingPool) internal view returns (uint256){
    uint256 _availableLiquidity;
    (,_availableLiquidity,,,,,,,,,,,) = _lendingPool.getReserveData(RAW_ETH_ASSET);// in ether
    return _availableLiquidity;
  }
```

..**Solidity** keeps complaining:

***YulException: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable dataEnd is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.***

This is the interface definition so of course I can't do anything about it.
Please what trick can I use to wangle the available liquidity out of the getReserveData function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
bytes4 private constant FUNC_SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256("getReserveData(address)"));

function getAvailableLiquidity(ILendingPool _lendingPool) internal view returns (uint256) {
    uint256[2] memory ret;
    bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(FUNC_SELECTOR, RAW_ETH_ASSET);

    assembly {
        let success := staticcall(
            gas,           // gas remaining
            _lendingPool,  // destination address
            add(data, 32), // input buffer (starts after the first 32 bytes in the `data` array)
            mload(data),   // input length (loaded from the first 32 bytes in the `data` array)
            ret,           // output buffer
            64             // output length
        )
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

    return ret[1];
}
```

Comment: Hmm,looks good at least it compiled after I set some value to the gas.

Can you explain a bit though how this works, so I will be able to replicate the solution for other similar issues I might have later?

Comment: @gbenroscience: Check out the comments next to each parameter.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration You do give off good vibes... and good answers, lol. 
Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The available liquidity is also provided by the Lending Pool Core:

```
interface ILendingPoolCore {
    function getReserveAvailableLiquidity(address _reserve) external view returns (uint256 _availableLiquidity);
}
```

Naturally, one would have to provide the address of the lending pool core instead of the address for lending pool:

```
function getAvailableLiquidity(ILendingPoolCore _lendingPoolCore) internal view returns (uint256 _availableLiquidity)
{
    return _lendingPoolCore.getReserveAvailableLiquidity(RAW_ETH_ASSET);
}
```